# ionic push Cannot read property 'init' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', ['ionic','angular-jwt'])

.controller('AppCtrl',function(){
var push = new Ionic.Push({
              "debug": true
            });

              push.saveToken(obj);
});
```

I can't register  token to device in other controller? my above work when I put it within the run() block. But why it isn't working in above case? I got an error of `Cannot read property 'init' of undefined`

Answer (score 1):

[Source](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ioni-push-notification/47034/2)

I believe that is the correct response. You've set your dev_push to false, correct? When you change dev_push to false, Push, from my understanding, doesn't work on the browser anymore, because you're not in development testing anymore.

However, if you were to use an emulator or attach your phone to it, you won't get that error anymore.

If you're using Android, you can download the ADB Chrome extension which will allow you to see the console logs on your phone, which is really handy!